# Get the total number of rows affected by the last statement (Postgres using PHP)

Tags: php, postgresql

I am doing paging and I am trying to get the total number of rows affected by the last statement. In MySQL you can use `FOUND_ROWS()` however I am using Postgres with PHP PDO. What I have is the following, however, it gets the total number of rows instead of the number of rows that was affected by the last statement which had a `WHERE` clauses. Here is my code:

```
        $result->execute();
        $orders = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $orders[] = [
                'orderdate' => $row['orderdate'],
                'shippeddate' => $row['shippeddate'],
                'shipname' => $row['shipname'],
                'shipaddress' => $row['shipaddress'],
                'shipcity' => $row['shipcity'],
                'shipcountry' => $row['shipcountry']
            ];
        }
        $result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows FROM orders');
        $result->execute();
```

Comment: To get the number of selected rows try `$result->`[rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) without running the `select count(*)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pg_affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php) function:

> **pg_affected_rows()** returns the number of tuples (instances/records/rows) affected by `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries.